# JavaScript HTML escape button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button which would encode my link into ascii and than on click redirect me to that new encoded address.

I already have the encoding part but the button just displays the converted code on click. I would like it instead to redirect me to that encoded page.

```
<body>

<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "https://webpage.com/submit.do?firstName=Ždžrgr&lastName=Žrđredj&phone=(24324) 09942&email=email@email.net”;
    var res = encodeURI(uri);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Can someone please help me with this? I am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `location.href` to redirect the page. `getElementById()` gets the element with id inside the paranthesis from the page for getting or setting the current value.

```
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "https://webpage.com/submit.do?firstName=Ždžrgr&lastName=Žrđredj&phone=(24324) 09942&email=email@email.net";
    var res = encodeURI(uri);
    location.href = res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `innerHTML` instead of changing the location. Try using

```
this.document.location = res;
```

instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. I replaced .innerHTML = res; with this.document.location = res; but that did nothing. Now its not even posting a link.